# pass user data to array and total results

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to pass user input to a 2 dimensional array. I ask the user the following:

- player number (Limit : 0 - 11)
- No of bases achieved ( Limit : 0 - 4)

I am trying to tally the number of bases achieved after the user ends. The code I have is:

```
    int p;         
    int[,] matrix1 = new int[11, 5];

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter player number");
        p = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int b;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Bases achieved");
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        matrix1[p, b] = b + 1;
        Console.WriteLine(matrix1[p, b]);
    } while (p < 99);
```

I realized this will only add 1 to whatever the user enters for bases achieved and will not actually tally the total. I am new at programming. Can anyone help by explaining how I can tally the results of each cell in this 12 by 5 array?

Comment: your question is a bit unclear.you want the sum of 4 bases of each user?ie the row sum?or do you want the column sum?

Comment: The idea is a coach enters a player number (0-11) then how many bases that player achieved on his turn at bat.(0-4) 4 would be a home run. when the coach enters 99 a total of the bases each player achieved during the game. I would then be displayed in a table format 12 rows(0-11) and 5 columns wide(0-4)

Comment: This is what I have coded so far:

Comment: int p;
        int[,] matrix1 = new int[12, 5];
        while(p != 22)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter player number (0 - 11");
            p = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int b;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Bases achieved (0 - 4)");
            b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            matrix1[p, b] = matrix1[p, b] + 1;
            Console.WriteLine(matrix1[p, b]);
        }

Comment: for (int y = 0; y < 13; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("player ({0}, obtained {1) =  {2}", y, matrix1[p, b]);
            }
        }

Comment: My while loop is set so if the user enters 22 it will drop to the bottom where the array is displayed, but when the user enters 22 I get an index out of range error. also on the bottom writeline statement where I am trying to display the contents of matrix1[p, b] I am getting a"the name b does not exist in the current context" does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$my_sum=0; //var for sum
foreach ($martix1 as $row) { //looping thorugh matrix by, fetching rows(first index)
    foreach ($row as $cell) {// fetching cells out of each row
        echo "$cell" . PHP_EOL; //printing each cell for your pleasure 
        $my_sum+=$cell; // adding to my_sum which holds the total sum
        }
    }

echo "the total sum is $my_sum";
```